# mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Attendance Monitoring\ITStudents.php on line 17

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my Database Connection code which I think should be correct but maybe not

```
<?
$database = "db_itweek_attendance";
$server = "localhost"; 
$db_user = "root"; 
$db_pass = ""; 
$db = mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($database,$db);
?>
```

This is my Query which I have no idea whats wrong

```
<?php
$query = "select * from itstudents";
$result=mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
extract($row);
echo "$LastName, $FirstName $MiddleName <br>";
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me :(

Comment: it seems like where you're running your `mysql_query` there is no database connection. Are you sure you ran your database connection code in the same file where `mysql_query` is?

Comment: Your $db link is NULL, looks like your connection is failing. Try some error checking: `code`$db =mysql_connect(...); if(!$db){die("error connecting");}

Comment: Yes I did. Its all written in one page. And I double checked my Database name in my PhpMyadmin and the error still occurs :(

Comment: @Naga I tried your error checking nothing happened. Still the same error :(

Comment: Also, I think ````mysql_query```` doesn't require the connection (that's mysqli which I encourage you to use), so it could be ````mysql_query($query);````

Comment: http://privatepaste.com/19bfbbcc13  full error checking, somewhere your db link drops to null

Comment: Also, `mysql_*` functions are **deprecated**! Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: `var_dump($db)`, right before your `mysql_query`. What do you get? (Likely: `null`. Question: why? Answer: we don't know, because we don't know how exactly your two pieces of code are connected.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the syntax error in the first line    `<?` instead of `<?php`

If you use short tags, this is might not issue.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. It wont solve the OP problem.

Comment: @lolka_bolka, i agree on u, but why cant this be the answer for the question.

Comment: DUDE ! OMG. Im F***ing Embarrassed right now! HAHAHAHAHAHA Your right!

Comment: Its a basic thing dude.. cheerssssssss.
@lolka_bolka: never judge the answer from ur mind. A small suggestion might be the solution for the problem. Cheers